# Video Editor similar to snapchat: issue with placing smiley

Tags: objective-c, snapchat, uivideoeditorcontroller

Working on video editor. able to place smiley on screen but unable to post it on video while exporting?

Tried to capture screenshot of the screen but it always captured with blackoverlay.

Please advise.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow and thank you for your question. Please take some time to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, so we can help you the best way.

Comment: Someone has asked a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443564/recording-custom-overlay-on-iphone